# Using the iPhone SDK Is it possible to display large content divided in the form of different pages?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Using the iPhone SDK Is it possible to display large content divided in the form of different pages?

I want the user to be able to view the content without having large amounts of scrolling.

I tried using UIWebView, but I couldn't found any auto scroll property for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIScrollView with ".pagingEnabled = YES".  This will allow you to add different UIView-based classes to a single Scroll View conroller and navigate up, down, left and right.  This si the controller used in the Weather app on the iPhone and iTouch.  Add mutiple cities and they are segmented into a swipeable navigation left and right.  It is also the base controller for the Springboard as well.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how they're doing it, the various eBook readers (Amazon Kindle, Stanza, Eucalpytus) break their content into pages nicely. It's certainly possible.